# Mocking Func property of a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, automocking

one of my repository class (say PersonRepo) has a delegate as its property something like this

```
private readonly Func<INameRepo> _nameRepo;
```

and apart from this it is inherited by a class which itself expects one more object (say the session).

Thus when i intialize this in my test I do something like

```
var funcNameRepo=autoMock.Mock<Func<INameRepo>>();
_personRepo= new PersonRepo(session,funcNameRepo.Object);
```

but when i run this test i get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`1[Repositories.Interfaces.INameRepo]' to type Moq.IMocked`1[System.Func`1[Repositories.Interfaces.INameRepo]]'.
```

what do you think I am doing wrong here. please help me.

Comment: You're syntax is getting garbled because of the generics.  Please format your code proeprly using the 10101 button.

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when the error is thrown? I'm not seeing anywhere in your code that looks like it should be expecting an IMocked<...>.

Comment: Could be an Automock issue as it's trying to do resolution of the children types. Can you try the same example without using Automock, just with MOQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why mock the `Func<INameRepo>`?  If you want to mock the `INameRepo`, create a mock for `INameRepo` and pass it to your `PersonRepo` via a lambda (which will be the `Func<INameRepo>`):

```
var nameRepo = autoMock.Mock<INameRepo>();
_personRepo = new PersonRepo(session, () => nameRepo.Object);
```

Comment: hey thanks. this works.. sorry took some time to reply.. i had removed the func from my constructor, but this suddenly hit me today.